# How to create DOS .com file with OpenWatcom `owcc`, but without the OpenWatcom libc?

Tags: c, dos, watcom

Here is a short C file `cu.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with OpenWatcom to a DOS .com file, the result is almost 3 KiB:

```
$ owcc -bcom -mcmodel=t -fno-stack-check -Os -s -march=i86 -W -Wall -Wextra -o cu.com cu.c
$ ls -l cu.com
-rwxr-x--- 1 pts pts 2938 Jun 20 19:26 cu.com
```

The smallest possible DOS .com file which does the same (just exits) is 1 byte long: it contains a single `ret` instruction (byte 0xc3).

How can I compile my `cu.c` file (with possibly some modifications, I don't care about argc or argv) to a smaller DOS .com file, without the OpenWatcom C library (libc), preferably less than 100 bytes? I will call DOS API functions (`int 0x21`) directly from my program, thus I won't need any of the OpenWatcom C library functions.

Please note that [COM executables with Open Watcom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408334/com-executables-with-open-watcom) doesn't answer my question, because the solutions presented there all include the OpenWatcom C library.

Comment: Used to use a DOS utility called `EXE2BIN` which would convert a "tiny" or "small" (??) model .exe to .com. I'm not sure that you can exit with `ret` though, it might need to call the terminate function.

Comment: exe2bin is cool, but it's unlikely to make a working .com file which is smaller than the .exe. The reason why I want a .com file is to save ~40 bytes of header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using `format dos com` instead of `system com` in my custom .lnk file. By doing so, the `libfile cstart_t.obj` in `system begin com` in `link.lnk` wasn't used, thus the startup code in the OpenWatcom C library wasn't referenced.

The resulting .com file is only 3 bytes (`xor ax, eax`; `ret`), which I'm happy with. To make it actually run, I have to prepare and add my `.obj` file though which contains `..start:` and sets up segments.

I'm still looking for a solution which doesn't need a custom .lnk file.